# Connection flight to domestic flight at Ataturk airport

Tags: air-travel, short-connections, isl

I am traveling from Oslo, Norway next week to Gazipasa in Turkey, but there is no direct flight so  I will land in Ataturk airport with  1hour and 15min time before my next flight to gazaipasa.

Is that enough time to get through passport/visa control and change to the domestic terminal ?

Comment: Are the flights on the same ticket?  Or did you purchase them separately?

Comment: @HankyPanky I've not flown through Ataturk airport in a while, but last time I did you could pass through immigration and transit between terminals without exiting the secured area - is this no longer true?

Comment: @HankyPanky fair enough :)

Comment: @HankyPanky Where exactly was this happening? The last time I was there was a bit earlier than you but as I recall, there is a completely separate path to the domestic terminal. The immigration line was certainly much much shorter than for international transit.

Comment: @Moo and Relaxed I have removed my comments since they don't specifically relate to OP's exact situation